# Calling a variable and the concept of variables

Tags: php

A have variable with the name a and a variable named b.

Try to print the value of the variable a using the variable b.

And what is the variable variable concept?

Comment: variable variable `$$var` lol that will mess with your head  http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php

Comment: Please share your code here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose that:

```
$b = "a";
$a = 1234;
echo $$b;
```

> Result is: 1234

it is the concept of variable of variable. means you can define variables dynamically.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if you literally meant variable variable

http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php

```
<?php
$a = 'hello';
?>
```

> A variable variable takes the value of a variable and treats that as the name of a variable. In the above example, hello, can be used as the name of a variable by using two dollar signs. i.e.

```
<?php
    $$a = 'world';
?>
```

> At this point two variables have been defined and stored in the PHP symbol tree: $a with contents "hello" and $hello with contents "world". Therefore, this statement:

```
<?php
    echo "$a ${$a}";
?>
```

> produces the exact same output as:

```
<?php
    echo "$a $hello";
?>
```

> i.e. they both produce: hello world.

First time I saw `$$var` I thought it was a typo, 4real.

In the above example from `http://php.net/manual` they are taking the value of `$a` and  creating a variable from it.  it's value `$a = 'hello'` becomes a variable `$hello` by using `$$a` then they set the new variable's value to `$hello = 'world'` here `$$a = 'world';` basically.

Personally I never use them, just because it makes reading the code more challenging then it should be.  ie. `extract()` is similar.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.extract.php

For me, they are just curious features of the language that don't serve any real purpose, but I look at `global` the same way too.   These things break my IDE's autocomplete so, while interesting, I find them of little practical use. In production code, readability is #1, followed by performance.